# Select text in the last div of class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some contenteditable divs with the same class, the div is dynamically created so I don't know how many there are.

```
<div class="scale1" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" contenteditable>0</div>
<div class="scale1" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" contenteditable>0</div>
<div class="scale1" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" contenteditable>0</div>
```

I want the text in the last one to be selected (like if you hold the left mouse button down over the text) with a button 
The obvious way in jquery:

```
 $(".scale1:last").click();
```

Doesn't work, it selects the hole page. 
I also thought about ways in javascript like Selection.selectAllChildren and Selection.addRange() but i have no elegant way of knowing the last div

Comment: well at least you have a goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to make text selection checkout [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128130/select-text-in-javascript) 
To reach your goal - replace ID selection with following code:

```
var query = document.querySelectorAll(".scale1"), 
    text = query[query.length-1];
```

Comment: Sorry but this dosen't select the text

Comment: Probably my question that was unclear, i want the text to be seleced like if the user clicked the left mousebutton and dragged over the text.

Comment: @user3320468, Oh, then checkout this stuff - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128130/select-text-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that, it uses getElementById and I don't have an id just a class

Comment: replace selection by ID with  var query = document.querySelectorAll(".scale1");
var text = query[query.length-1];

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`$('.scale1:last').text()`

or

`$('.scale1').last().text()`

Either would work, even for dynamically added elements.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/MLBCU/1/)

Comment: I want to select the text, like if a user hold the left mousebutton and selects the text..